# Actions must be a plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions error

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, redux, redux-thunk

i am creating a form where user can submit their name,caption and a url for a image. At backend i am using express and mongodb.
i am trying to dispatch the createMeme and it will take memeData as data. Now when i am trying to dispatch i get above error but if i simply dispatch it as  dispatch(createMeme) i dont get the error. but i need to send the memeData

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
/*Provider keeps track of the store in which there is global state which can be accessed from this store* */
import {createStore,applyMiddleware,compose} from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import App from './App'
import reducers from './redux/reducers'
/**firstly create store, it takes two parameters 1) reducer 2) compose*/
/**Redux Thunk is middleware that allows you to return functions, rather than just actions, within Redux. This allows for delayed actions, including working with promises.

One of the main use cases for this middleware is for handling actions that might 
not be synchronous, for example, using axios to send a GET request. 
Redux Thunk allows us to dispatch those actions asynchronously and resolve 
each promise that gets returned. */
const store = createStore(reducers,compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store = {store}>
    <App/>
  </Provider>

,document.getElementById('root'));
```

```
export const getMemes = () => {
    const action = async(dispatch)=> {
       try {
           const {data} = await api.fetchMemes();
           dispatch({type: 'FETCH_ALL',
           payload: data});
       } catch (error) {
           console.log(error.message);
       }
        
    }

}
export const createMeme = (meme) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const {data} = await api.createMeme(meme);
        dispatch({type:'CREATE_MEME',payload:data});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}
```

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import {TextField,Button,Typography,Paper,Box} from '@material-ui/core'
import useStyles from './styles'
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import { createMeme } from '../api'
const Form = () => {
    const [memeData,setMemeData] = useState({
            name: '',
            caption:'',
            url: ''
    })
    const classes = useStyles();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const handleSubmit = (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        dispatch(createMeme(memeData))
    }
   
    return (
         <Paper className = {classes.paper}>
         <form  className = {classes.form} autoComplete = "off" noValidate className = {classes.form} onSubmit ={handleSubmit} >
            <Typography variant = "h6">Create Meme</Typography>
            <TextField className= {classes.input} name = "Name"
            variant = "outlined"
            label= "Name"
            
            
            fullWidth
            value = {memeData.name}
            onChange = {(event) => setMemeData({...memeData, name: event.target.value})}
            ></TextField>
             <TextField  className= {classes.input}  name = "Caption"
            variant = "outlined"
            label= "Caption"
            
            fullWidth
            value = {memeData.caption}
            onChange = {(event) => setMemeData({...memeData, caption: event.target.value})}
            
            ></TextField>
             <TextField  className= {classes.input}  name = "URL"
            variant = "outlined"
            label= "URL"
          
            fullWidth
            value = {memeData.url}
            onChange = {(event) =>setMemeData({...memeData, url: event.target.value})}
            ></TextField>
         </form>
         <Box textAlign = 'center'>
         <Button className = {classes.buttonSubmit}  variant = "contained" color = "primary" type="Submit" onClick = {handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
         </Box>
     </Paper>
    )
}

export default Form
```

Comment: Are you dispatching the correct createMeme, the `createMeme = (meme) => async (dispatch) =>` one? What is your createStore code? What is getMemes supposed to be and why assign something to action and never use it? I think that should be: `getMemes = () => async(dispatch) => {`

Comment: @HMR  yes i am dispatching the correct createMeme. i have added the create store code in the post . i am using getMemes but not in the file shown above it is used in another file

Comment: does `createStore(reducers,undefined, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));` work?

Comment: actuallly i had imported actions from wrong file hence was facing errors. @HMR can you tell how can i resolve this error require('mongoose-type-url');
^
ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: @HMR that issue is resolved now actually i was importing the actions from wrong file. can u help resolve this error                                                                     require('mongoose-type-url');
^ReferenceError: require is not defined